# Checking nested property that can be null

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I've the following data in my collection:

```
{ colour: { r: 0, g: 0, b: 0 }},
{ colour: null },
```

How can I find all the documents that have `colour == null` or `color.r` between some values?

I've tried

```
.find({ where: { $or: [{colour: null}, {"colour.r": {$gt: 0, $lt: 100}}]}})
```

but of course this gives me `cannot read property 'r' of null` for null rows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [**`$where`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#considerations) only if there is no other way to express your query

```js
db.test.find({$or: [{"colour": null}, {"colour.r": {$gt: 0, $lt: 100}}]})
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless don't need a single query, you could run 2 queries:

1. Find all documents `where color == null`
2. Find all documents `where color != null and color between 0 and 100`

Comment: Using two queries, there's a slight chance for the same document to be returned twice -- if it was concurrently updated by an other client.

Answer (score 1):

For sake of completeness:

```
db.test.find({$nor: [{"colour.r": {$lte: 0}}, {"colour.r": {$gte: 100}}]})
```

[`$nor`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nor/) will match all documents that **fail** the expressions.

Here, you don't have to explicitly test for `null` as it is neither greater nor lower than any number -- hence, will fail the tests, just like any number *in* the range (0,100)<sup>1</sup>

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>Exclusive. If you need to find every document in the range [0,100] inclusive, replace `$gte` (resp. `$lte`) by `$gt` (resp. `$lt`).</sub>